# Changing a panel color of another form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

We have 2 forms, `A` and `B`. And the `B` form has a `Panel` in it. (`Panel`'s name `C`)
I want to change the `Color` of the `Panel` in form `B` by using the form `A`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
B cr = new B();
cr.C.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255);
```

This code  does not give me any errors nor warnings but still does not work.

Comment: use a debugger to prove that execution ever reaches this point, and that `B` is actually this instance of your form that you're showing.

Comment: You are creating new object of B, and changes are stick to this new object cr only. You need to find original object which is visible on forms.

Comment: I have had issues with trying to modify controls on other forms that are down to the timing of events - it could be you are changing the background colour before the control is initialised - which can happen only when the form is displayed.

Comment: Though having created a basic Form1 with only a button & Form2 with only a panel - changing the background either before or after showing the new form works correctly for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `OpenForms` which will do the job for you.

You have Form1 , Form2 with a panel. First Make the `panel` modifier `public`

Let's say you opened the `Form2` by this code from `Form1` :

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Show();
```

Then from Form1 use this code :

```
Form2 frm = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
frm.panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

And here is the result :
[image]

Comment: That worked. Also, is it possible to change the panel color if the form is closed? and how.

Comment: Yes it's possible, you can change it from the first code before opening the form. Just call `frm.panel1.BackColor = Color.Red; ` even if you don't want to open the form. Just changing it will work also.Complete code looks like :  `Form2 frm = new Form2();` then `frm.panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;`

Comment: Be aware : when changing the color without opening the form, you have to open the same instance when you want to open it. I mean you have to call `frm.Show();` **without** creating a new instance like `Form2 frm = new Form2();`

Comment: I just tried that, just gives me an error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: I tried it and it worked ! Just those two lines will do the job ! `Form2 frm = new Form2();`  `frm.panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;` It worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to invoke the thread. Create the method in your class B `SetColor()`.

```
public void SetColor()
{
    MethodInvoker Invoker = new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        C.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255);
    });

    this.Invoke(Invoker);
}
```

Then call this method `SetColor()` instead of directly accessing the `BackColor` property of another form.

```
B cr = new B();
cr.Show();
cr.SetColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if you want to change that color more than once. If yes create public method with color parameter on Form 'B' like this:

```
public partial class B : Form 
{
   ...
   public void ChangePanelColor(Color clr)
   {
      panel.BackColor= clr;
   }
   ...
}
```

After u've done this you can call this method from your from A like this:

```
public partial class A : Form
{
   private B secondForm;
   ...
   // event handler for button with text 'Show Form2'
   private void ShowNewForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      secondForm = new B();
      secondForm.Show();
   }

   // event handler for button with text 'Change panel color'
   private void ChangePanelColor(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      secondForm?.ChangePanelColor(Color.Black);
   }
}
```